# Postman escaping form-data to API causing unexpected token error

Tags: json, escaping, postman

I am trying to use Postman to troubleshoot an API error I am getting. I am using OAuth to authenticate and so I am posting headers and form-data. However, it seems the error I have is related to the form-data. I have also tried with the 'Content-Type' to be 'application/json; charset=utf-8' and without. Same results.

```
{
    "error": "795: unexpected token at '------WebKitFormBoundaryoRBw9tLdltLHfrtU\r\nContent-   Disposition: form-data; name=\"topic\"\r\n\r\ncheckouts/update\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryoRBw9tLdltLHfrtU\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"address\"\r\n\r\nhttps://mysite.co/checkout/\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryoRBw9tLdltLHfrtU\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"format\"\r\n\r\njson\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryoRBw9tLdltLHfrtU--\r\n'"
}
```

I think Postman is escaping my data before the API can read it in correctly. Any ideas how to get Postman to stop escaping my data prematurely? There seems to be no issues on it.

Body of request:

```
"webhook":[{"topic": "checkouts/update","address": "https://mysite.co/checkout","format": "json"}]
```

Comment: Can you show us the body of the request ? Maybe the issue is hiding in there. I don't think Postman is the problem.

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard Sure, here it is.

Comment: Most of the APIs I've used needed the Json property to be enclosed in a json object like so: `{ "webhook":[{"topic": "checkouts/update","address": "https://mysite.co/checkout","format": "json"}] }`

Comment: That was indeed the error. Could you add that as an answer? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose your JSON property inside a JSON object, that's usually what APIs are expecting.

```
{ 
    "webhook":[
        {"topic": "checkouts/update","address": "https://mysite.co/checkout","format": "json"}
    ] 
}
```